# The multi-part identifier could not be bound in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server and I have created three tables `students`, `phones` and `stud_phone`.

The relation between `student` and `phone` is many-many the `stud_phone` table contains the two foreign keys from `student` and `phone` tables.

What I want to achieve is that I want to retrieve the record of student of Id1 and their respective phones which he/she has but I'm unable to do it.

I get this error:

> multipart identifier could not be bound

Here is my schema:

[image]

Here is my query :

```
select * 
from student, phone
join stud_phone on student.stId = 1
                and student.stId = stud_phone.stId
                and phone.phId = stud_phone.phId
```

Comment: If you remove the commas from your `join` clause, then it might be easier for you.  `... from table join table2 on table.field = table2.field join table3 on ...`

Comment: Aside from mixing ANSI-89 and ANSI-92 style joins ( a really bad idea) you have a syntax issue. Look here. "stud_phone" That is neither a table nor a column. You also really should use aliases to make this a lot easier on yourself.

Comment: @sgeddes.... yes but i want to retrieve the records from two tables

Comment: @SeanLange  .... m not getting what you are suggesting sir

Comment: For starters be consistent with your join syntax and use the nearer (been available for more than 25 years now) syntax. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: It seems that the problem is more complex than just joins. posting pictures of your data is not a great plan. Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean:

```
select * 
from student, phone
join stud_phone on student.stId = 1
                and student.stId = stud_phone.stId
                and phone.phId = stud_phone.phId
```

Replace the '_' in student_Id with a '.': student.stId

Comment: sorry that mistake caused in typing sir but the issue is that i want to retrieve the record from many to many which is giving me an error

Comment: This error "multipart identifier could not be bound" is not a many to many problem.  It is a syntax error.  Fixed by my answer.  Or, run my code and post the complete error message. (usually 2 lines)

Comment: @Inam, come on, how come it works. You are not reading comments.

Comment: @Inam, ROFL. You are just marking replies as answers one by one, without having an idea what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * 
from student s
left join stud_phone sp on s.stId=sp.stId
inner join phone p on p.phId = sp.phId
where s.stId = 1;
```

Here s, sp and p are "local aliases" and just used for the purpose of less typing (it has useful benefits in other places). Note that using old style joins is asking for trouble, it implicitly creates an inner join (but a student might have 0 phones).

Comment: yes sir this is what i needed you are a pro thank you sir :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is what you meant:

```
SELECT s.*, sp.*
FROM student s
INNER JOIN stud_phone sp ON sp.stId = s.stId
INNER JOIN phone p ON p.phId = s.phId
```

*NOTE: You really should think about swapping into a more reasonable style of joins here. ANSI-92 is now old enough to drink. ;)*

Comment: ROFL - "ANSI-92 is now old enough to drink."

Comment: You shouldn't use inner join. It assumes student have at least one phone but many-to-many means he could have none.

Comment: it is good but what if there is no phone for a student than it will return nothing because it is inner join here

Comment: @Inam, finally you started to see it. I was trying to say that all along. Just use LEFT join as in my reply.

Answer (score 2):

the below query should return students with their phone numbers. I have used tables aliases and   ANSI-92 join syntax

```
select s.*, p.* 
from student as s
join stud_phone as sp on s.stId = sp.stId
inner join phone as p on p.phId = sp.phId
where s.stId = 1
```

**Update** : if the relation between student and stud_phone is zero to many, then you should use LEFT JOIN between `student` and `stud_phone` tables.

Comment: What if that student had no phones?

Comment: @Inam, no it is working by chance. You shouldn't use inner join.

Comment: @CetinBasoz - You might be correct, but OP had all inner joins in the query, so I just rewritten the query.

Comment: I think he didn't simply wanted to mean "rewrite my query". What I am saying IS correct, not MIGHT.

Comment: yes inner join is not correct in here it will return nothing if no phone for a student

Comment: @CetinBasoz - agree, but the OP's main issue was the syntax and not the wrong data. if the requirement is to have at-least one phone number then it should work. I am totally agree with your comment and updated my answer as well.